# Java Plugin issue on chrome browser

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, java

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. Installed java on this.

Version 1.7.0_55. trying to enable java on google chrome but have failed.

I symbolic linked libnpjp2.so to /opt/google/chrome/plugins

tried icetea plugin too

it works fine in for firefox. But in chrome it says install java runtime environment from www.java.com

Can someone please help me out. I am stuck up from past 2 days

Comment: please let me know if there is anything else to be shared with you guys

Comment: This is already reported.<br>
Check [this][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/470594/how-do-i-get-java-working-on-google-chrome-35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi java only function by chrome 34, chrome 35 dont support java..

you should install chrome 34 by .deb

http://mirror.pcbeta.com/google/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/

Comment: Solved my issue with chrome 34

Answer (score 5):

Just a heads up, Google has fully dropped Netscape Plug-in API (NPAPI) in one of the last Chrome and Chromium updates.  This has been [planned](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) for some time. From what I'm seeing, this means that neither the icetea nor the Oracle Java plugins will work in Chrome/Chromium until they are updated use one of their other plugin APIs (Pepper?).

For now, this means that I have to switch to Firefox for my primary work browser after using Chrome/Chromium for many years. I still have to use the Java web plugins for meetings at work.

Comment: And of course, ajit had already answered **11** hours before I did as a comment to the main question...

Answer (score 0):

If you do have Java installed, you need to install `icedtea` plugin.

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```

After Installing this package just restart your browser and Java should be working.

Comment: I tried this but it only works in firefox not on google chrome. When i restart the crome browser it java (TM) is required to display some elements on this page

Comment: It's probably because Java is disabled in your browser. Go to Control Panel, click on the Java icon and click the Security tab on the dialog box that opens up and make sure that the Enable Java content in the browser box is checked

Comment: Plesae let me where to find control panel on ubuntu..Thank u

Comment: Please make sure java version is compatible with `icedtea-plugin`    if java version is 1.6 then install `sudo apt-get install icedtea6-plugin`. if java version is 1.7 then `sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin`

Comment: Hi tech guru, installed icedtea-7 plugin still am facing the same issue.