# How do I get Java plugin working on Google Chrome?

Tags: java, google-chrome

Google has updated its **Chrome browser** to version 35. This new version uses **Aura** in place of GTK2 and no longer supports NPAPI plugins like Java (both OpenJDK and Oracle). PPAPI plugins like PepperFlash still work.

My school uses Google Chrome and Google apps every day and this looks like a potentially big problem for some of the educational websites we use. Has anyone run into a solution or workaround to get Java working?

[This WEB UPD8 article confirms that Java does not work](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/google-chrome-stable-35-for-linux.html).

Comment: Java will NOT work on Chrome, like any other NPAPI plugin, unless it will be moved to the PPAPI architecture. References: [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/linux/D5fxmTQZOEw) and [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/linux/FnQ4zb3VPbQ)

Comment: If available, you could download the jar file and run it on your desktop instead of inside Chrome.

Comment: Java has not been supported on Chrome for ages on OS X so anyone could see it coming on Linux...

Comment: I have Chromium version 34 in synaptic for ubuntu12.4LTS, seems to work fine, java too. So that is my solution for now. Jes

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You cannot get Java to work on Chrome 35. Its because of the removal of the older plugin NPAPI. 
I have raised a bug report. Awaiting a proper response from the devs. 
The bug report is here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375909. 
You can try and follow the thread for this discussion here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/xEbgvWE7wMk

**UPDATE**
Looks like we are going to be stuck here for quite a while. My bug report was merged into the parent bug and it's been set as won't fix. Here it is : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=363053

**UPDATE2**
A relevant question was posted to Oracle. Not much traction. You guys can start a discussion on that thread. Go here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3511913

**To all of you:** To keep Chrome functioning, please downgrade your GOogle Chrome to 34. You can download the deb here: http://mirror.pcbeta.com/google/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/.
Then use synaptic package manager or use the commandline to lock upgrades for google-chrome-stable package. Chrome 34 doesn't have any glaring bugs, so you can use it safely for the next 3 months. I am hoping by that time some patch will be added.

Comment: If you have already launched Chrome 35, then your user profile directory will be incompatible with Chrome 34. If you want to downgrade without losing functionality or data, see http://superuser.com/questions/757941/how-to-downgrade-from-chrome-35-to-34-without-losing-data.

Comment: Good point, but since everything is synced with Google , you should not have problems in restoring even after deleting the folder

Comment: Unless you don't use Google Sync ;)

Comment: Interesting is that Chrome for Windows still supports NPAPI plugins.

Comment: Looks like Oracle took down the link... I guess that answers if they are making one or not ;)

Comment: Downgrade isn't an option. When NPAPI is needed I use firefox.

Comment: Here's a similar (more recent?) thread in the Oracle "community" forum: [Java on Chrome -- What are you doing Oracle?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3700718).

Answer (score 2):

You **CAN** get Java to work on Chrome, or at least enable the NPAPI plug-in for it... temporarily. The option is being removed altogether in Chrome 45. (Currently we are at 43, estimate is September 2015.)

Note that enabling NPAPI doesn't necessarily mean the Java Applet will work... I tried it with one and it didn't. This likely is due to having the latest Java installed, which pretty much locks down any web access anyways. Which is a shame, since so many nifty Java-enhanced web services had been created (such as http://www.freerouting.net/ .)

In any case, the option to enable NPAPI is located by browsing to:

`chrome://flags/#enable-npapi`

Again, your mileage may vary (YMMV.)

Comment: Using Chrome Version 43.0.2357.125 (64-bit), there is not `#enable-npapi` option for `flags`.  After much digging, it seems that you just cannot use Java in Google Chrome anymore ...and that is pretty sh*tty of the Google Chrome team. My daughter needs it for school.