# Installing IcedTeaPlugin for Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, plugins, icedtea

I am trying to get the java plugin to work on chrome but have failed so far. I made symbolic links for the two files : IcedTeaPlugin.so and libjavaplugin.so

I made the links in the file section /opt/google/chrome/plugins/, where it should be. Yet when I go to the browser the plugin does not work. The plugin does not even show up on the chrome plugins page. I have restarted the browser as well. Is there something I forgot to do when I made the links?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/470594/how-do-i-get-java-working-on-google-chrome-35. Short version: You can't use Java in Chrome(ium) 35 (and beyond).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't work with latest Chrome/Chromium. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/xEbgvWE7wMk

Comment: is there any other way to install java on chrome then? or will it never be supported