# Java plugins for Chrome 45+?

Tags: java, google-chrome

I have been having trouble with Java in my Chrome dev build (48), and all the posts about Java for Chrome are old and potentially outdated. Is there any new developments for Java in Chrome now?

Comment: The answer is NO.

Comment: @Pilot6: Can you make this the answer to this question?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Converted to an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get Java plugin working on Google Chrome?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470594/how-do-i-get-java-plugin-working-on-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no development for Java to get the plugin compatible with Chrome PPAPI interface so far.

At least there is nothing I heard of.